# How to use loop for retrieve distance between multiple coordinates from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
        var theta = lon1-lon2;
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        if (dist > 1) {
            dist = 1;
        }
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        return dist;
    }
}
```

```
console.log(distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, "K"));
```

My array:
[0 … 99]
0: {provider: "fused", locationProvider: 1, time: 1582829443960, latitude: 45.9605221, longitude: 13.6437692, …}
1: {provider: "fused", locationProvider: 1, time: 1582829453971, latitude: 45.9605234, longitude: 13.6437679, …}
2: {provider: "fused", locationProvider: 1, time: 1582829472537, latitude: 45.9605234, longitude: 13.6437679, …}
3: {provider: "fused", locationProvider: 1, time: 1582829502534, latitude: 45.960517, longitude: 13.6437747, …}
4: {provider: "fused", locationProvider: 1, time: 1582829503566, latitude: 45.960517, longitude: 13.6437747, …}
5: {provider: "fused", locationProvider: 1, time: 1582829893219, latitude: 45.9605249, longitude:

I need to get first distance between first two different coordinates, then from second and calculate how much calculate has each coordinate.

```
    var distanceChange = currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres;
    distanceTotal += distanceChange;

    $("#test").html("Total distance " + distanceChange + " m");
```

Comment: Can yo give more details about what you're trying to achieve, use case talking? Are you trying to calculate total distance from One Location to another (L1 to L4) : `L1- (2000m) ->L2 - (1300m) -> L3 -> 5200m -> L4` ? Or Shortest Path form L1 to L4? Or Closest Location to L1 (L2 or L3 or L4, etc.)? Have you considered using a Graph Data Structure that already has methods to deal more easily with those kind of Graph, Nodes,  Edges and Distance calculations?

Comment: Or do you want, for each Location, Loop through all other Locations and calculate the distance? Like for L1, get `L1-L2`, `L1-L3`, `L1-L4`. For L2 get `L2-L1`, `L2-L3` and `L2-L4`, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to loop the array with a `for` loop:

```
var result = []
for (var i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
    result.push(distance(array[i].latitude, array[i].longitude,distance(array[i+1].latitude, 
    array[i+1].longitude,"K"));
}
console.log(result);
```